# Nestjs Validation failed (numeric string is expected) inside controller's nested route

Tags: nestjs

I have a controller using **@Controller('tasks')** decorator. Inside this controller, I have a route **@Get('/week')**, normally the request should go **localhost:4000/tasks/week** but it is returning a bad request:

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Validation failed (numeric string is expected)"
}
```

Below is my code:

```
@Controller('tasks')
@UseGuards(AuthGuard())
export class TasksController {
  constructor(private tasksService: TasksService) { }

  @Get('/:id')
  getTaskById(@Param('id', ParseIntPipe) id: number): Promise<Task> {
    return this.tasksService.getTaskById(id);
  }

  @Get('/week')
  getTasksByWeek(@GetUser() user: User): Promise<Task[]> {
    return this.tasksService.getTasksByWeek(user);
}
```

Removing the **/week** from Get() decorator works but not adding it.

**Expected result**: return data

**Actual result**:

```
 {
    "statusCode": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Validation failed (numeric string is expected)"
}
```

Answer (score 19):

I found a fix for this issue. Routes such as Get('week') or routes that accept parameters should be lined before routes with base controller route.

Assume we have a route @GET() like below that gets all the tasks:

```
 @Get()
  getTasks(@GetUser() user: User): Promise<Task[]> {
    return this.tasksService.getTasksByWeek(user);
}
```

How it should be in the code:

```
@Controller('tasks')
@UseGuards(AuthGuard())
export class TasksController {
  constructor(private tasksService: TasksService) { }

  @Get('/:id')
  getTaskById(@Param('id', ParseIntPipe) id: number): Promise<Task> {
    return this.tasksService.getTaskById(id);
  }

  @Get('/week')
  getTasksByWeek(@GetUser() user: User): Promise<Task[]> {
    return this.tasksService.getTasksByWeek(user);
}
 @Get()
  getTasks(@GetUser() user: User): Promise<Task[]> {
    return this.tasksService.getTasksByWeek(user);
}
```

Comment: that's weird solution

Answer (score 18):

As answers given are not really explaining the "why" of this behaviour, here's a quick explanation:

**It's just a matter of ordering and what route is met First**: "week" is mistaken with an ":id", like 123, 204...etc.

As your router tries the first route that meet route requirements (pattern in this case), your request is forwarded to /id route. It happens in every http framework with a router.

Validation occurs later on. So **in short, the only thing that matters in route selection, is pattern, not validation set in it.**

This ordering is really important, as you'll face same exact issue in all major http framework with a router.

Comment: Yes. Requests are routed to another controller.

Answer (score 5):

Just put **@Get("any-string")** route above route **@Get(":id")** that takes the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to change the order of `@Get('/week')` and `@Get('/:id')` as shown below. The Bad Request error occurred because the `'/week'` route was interpreted as a URL parameter for `:id` in `@Get('/:id')`. It's essential to define specific URL routes (like `'/week'`) before those with URL parameters (like `'/:id'`). The sequence in which routes are defined is crucial.

```
    @Controller('tasks')
    @UseGuards(AuthGuard())
    export class TasksController {
      constructor(private tasksService: TasksService) { }
    
      @Get('/week')
      getTasksByWeek(@GetUser() user: User): Promise<Task[]> {
        return this.tasksService.getTasksByWeek(user);
      }

      @Get('/:id')
      getTaskById(@Param('id', ParseIntPipe) id: number): Promise<Task> {
        return this.tasksService.getTaskById(id);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are also beginner in Nestjs like me, then make sure you are not committing these basic mistakes,

1. **argument passed from playground/FrontEnd and parameter received at Resolver function should be same** e.g

[image]

[image]

at both sending and receiving ends here, string should be `itemCategoryId`

2. **If parameter to be received in Resolver function is nullable, then you should mention that** I am providing example of this for Nestjs, you can google the syntax for other frameworks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue because I had this statement in my "main.ts" file, which I needed since I wanted to run a custom transformer decorator for trimming DTO inputs.

```js
app.useGlobalPipes(
  new ValidationPipe({
    transform: true,
  })
);
```

Due to this, every route was breaking and giving the same validation error. The reason for this error is that I had some dynamic routes that have `ParseInt` directives on them like `/users/:id`. If you remove the `ParseInt` directives, the routes work fine.

To fix this issue, I had to create a custom extension for `ValidationPipe` and use that instead of the plain validation pipe. This is how it goes.

```js
import { ValidationPipe as NestValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';

export class ValidationPipe extends NestValidationPipe {
  constructor() {
    super({ transform: true });
  }
}
```

This enables me to successfully have my decorator up and running along with my APIs.